# Mirgrating Document Server to the Cloud

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

A client of mine is having problems hosting their own document server so they are thinking about moving the their document server and application server to the cloud. The problem is, we had a application that scanned the documents into a particular folder on the document server (internal network), now with the cloud this application may need to be revised to send the documents. FTP is out. We are looking for a host service that allows us to map the folder on the server or that would enable us to upload the documents via HTTP/HTTPS. Can anyone suggest a service that I could use to accomplish this ? Please let me knows thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: Well for 1, the application ASP.NET app synchronize with the document server to give a list of all the files on the server, I want to ensure that this is not affected, because this is a integral part of the client's operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at a WebDAV provider. I do personal doc backup and management against my FastMail DAV storage area and it works fine. All you need is a good WebDAV client. I use a Python lib, but there are commercial and free clients for most languages.